# Speeding up itertools combinations with cython

Tags: python, cython, python-itertools

I have the following code to generate all possible combinations in specified range using itertools but I cant get any speed improvements from using the code with cython. Original code is this:

```
from itertools import *

def x(e,f,g):
    a=[]        
    for c in combinations(range(e, f),g):
        d = list((c))
        a.append(d)
```

and after declaring types for cython:

```
from itertools import *

cpdef x(int e,int f,int g):        
    cpdef tuple c
    cpdef list a
    cpdef list d

    a=[]        
    for c in combinations(range(e, f),g):    
        d = list((c))
        a.append(d)
```

I saved the latter as `test_cy.pyx` and compiled using `cythonize -a -i test_cy.pyx`

After compiling, I created a new script with the following code and ran it:

```
import test_cy

test_cy.x(1,45,6)
```

I didnt get any significant speed improvement, still took about the same time as the original script, about 10.8 sec.

Is there anything I did wrong or is  itertools already so optimised that there cant be any bigger improvements to its speed?

Comment: I suspect your code still makes heavy use of Python functions.  `combinations` is a generator that is already written in `C`.  `a` and `d` are still Python objects.

Comment: @hpaulj Sure yeh I guess being written in `C` thats about as fast as it can go. Thanks

Comment: It would almost certainly be possible to write a faster version of `combination` that only deals with integer ranges (itertools can handle any Python iterable, and that may be slower). However, you need to do this from scratch - you won't get any improvements just calling `itertools.combination` through Cython.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks, understood. Yes after following the main answer as well I realised cython improved the speed by 2x after I got rid of creating the list of lists which means as you said that the rest of the time is being spent mostly on the itertools function so cython couldnt improve the speed any further. Im happy with the speedup so far but will certainly look into developing an itertools function for integers only for comparison. Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, you should not expect cython to speed-up your code because the most of the time the algorithm spends in itertools and creation of lists.

Because I'm curios to see how `itertools`'s generic implementation fares against old-school-tricks, let's take a look at this Cython implementation of "all subsets k out of n":

```
%%cython

ctypedef unsigned long long ull

cdef ull next_subset(ull subset):
   cdef ull smallest, ripple, ones
   smallest = subset& -subset      
   ripple = subset + smallest    
   ones = subset ^ ripple    
   ones = (ones >> 2)//smallest 
   subset= ripple | ones    
   return subset


cdef subset2list(ull subset, int offset, int cnt):  
    cdef list lst=[0]*cnt #pre-allocate
    cdef int current=0;
    cdef int index=0
    while subset>0:
        if((subset&1)!=0):
            lst[index]=offset+current
            index+=1
        subset>>=1
        current+=1
    return lst

def all_k_subsets(int start, int end, int k):
    cdef int n=end-start      
    cdef ull MAX=1L<<n;
    cdef ull subset=(1L<<k)-1L;
    lst=[]
    while(MAX>subset):
         lst.append(subset2list(subset, start, k))
         subset=next_subset(subset)
    return lst
```

This implementation uses some well-known bit-tricks and has the limitation, that it only works for at most 64 elements.

If we compare both approaches:

```
>>> %timeit x(1,45,6)
2.52 s ± 108 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit all_k_subsets(1,45,6)
1.29 s ± 5.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The speed-up of factor 2 is quite disappointing.

However, the bottle-neck is the creation of the lists and not the calculation itself - it is easy to check, that without list creation the calculation would take about 0.1 seconds.

My take away from it: if you are serious about speed you should not create so many lists but proceed the subset on the fly (best in cython) - a speed-up of more than 10 is possible. If it is a must to have all subsets as lists, so you cannot expect a huge speed-up.

Comment: Great answer. I wonder how the code would fare under PyPy which is able to optimize things like list creation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the well explained solution! Yes using the list of tuples from itertools as it is without converting it to a list of lists has cut the run time from about 10sec to 4 sec. Using cython further reduced it to 2 seconds. I didnt realise I could do everything I needed to do without converting to lists as I'm still learning. Cheers:)